# Stripping empty elements from lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a python data structure like this

```
dl= [{'plat': 'unix',   'val':['', '',   '1ju', '', '',   '202', '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'Ios',    'val':['', '',   '',    '', 'Ty', '',    'Jk', '']},
     {'plat': 'NT',     'val':['', '',   1,     '', '' ,  '202', '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'centOs', 'val':['', '',   '',    '', '',   '202', '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'ubuntu', 'val':['', 'KL', '1',   '', '',   '',    '',   '9i0']}]
                                ^                ^
                                |                |
                                \                /
                                   Delete these
```

I am trying to delete the position in the list `'val'` where the values in the same column in each list are empty. For example, position 0 and 3 in the list(dl). I am trying to get an output like this:

```
Output= [{'plat': 'unix',   'val':['',   '1ju', '',   '202', '',   '']},
         {'plat': 'Ios',    'val':['',   '',    'Ty', '',    'Jk', '']},
         {'plat': 'NT',     'val':['',   1,     '' ,  '202', '',   '']},
         {'plat': 'centOs', 'val':['',   '',    '',   '202', '',   '']},
         {'plat': 'ubuntu', 'val':['KL', '1',   '',   '',    '',   '9i0']}]
```

Comment: You want to delete all of the empty elements?

Comment: Try to make the example more simple. Why does your code example include `'plat':'unix'`? Also it's not clear for me what you mean by "position 0 and 3 in the list(dl)": In the output list, you changed all positions.

Comment: to delete the position where the element is empty in all of the lists like position 0 is empty in all 5 list('val')

Comment: @TylerAndFriends I think he want to remove multiple continue blanks `''` into single  `''`

Comment: It's unclear what the algorithm is that relates the input to the output in your example.

Comment: @rockyrock Check [this code](http://codepad.org/n4O3L7hL)

Comment: @rockyrock Improve your question. Explain your input and desired output..

Comment: Wt i am trying to do is delete the element which is empty in all the list i have mentioned above like example val[0] is empty in all the 5 list i mentioned so in the output i delete that

Comment: @rockyrock Repeating yourself in near identical language and providing little to no additional information doesn't add clarity to your problem. I think what you're trying to say is "if val[n] is empty in all plat's, remove val[n] from val for all plats".  Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do this in two steps.  First, find indices to remove:

```
lists = [e['val'] for e in dl]
idx_to_remove = [i for i, elem in enumerate(map(any, zip(*lists))) if not elem]
```

Second, let's filter original lists:

```
for l in lists:
    l[:] = [elem for i, elem in enumerate(l) if i not in idx_to_remove]
```

Result:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(dl)
[{'plat': 'unix', 'val': ['', '1ju', '', '202', '', '']},
 {'plat': 'Ios', 'val': ['', '', 'Ty', '', 'Jk', '']},
 {'plat': 'NT', 'val': ['', 1, '', '202', '', '']},
 {'plat': 'centOs', 'val': ['', '', '', '202', '', '']},
 {'plat': 'ubuntu', 'val': ['KL', '1', '', '', '', '9i0']}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dl= [{'plat': 'unix',   'val':['', '', '1ju', '', '', '202',  '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'Ios',    'val':['', '',  '',   '', 'Ty', '',     'Jk', '']},
     {'plat': 'NT',     'val':['', '',   1,   '', '' , '202', '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'centOs', 'val':['', '',  '',   '', '',  '202', '',   '']},
     {'plat': 'ubuntu', 'val':['', 'KL','1',  '', '',   '',   '',   '9i0']}]

def empty_indices(lst):
  return {i for i,v in enumerate(lst) if not v}

# Need to special-case the first one to initialize the set of "emtpy" indices.
remove_idx = empty_indices(dl[0]['val'])
# Here we do the first one twice.  We could use itertools.islice but it's 
# probably not worth the miniscule speedup.
for item in dl:
  remove_idx &= empty_indices(item['val'])

for item in dl:
    item['val'] = [k for i,k in enumerate(item['val']) if i not in remove_idx]

# print the results.
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dl)
```

Comment: After `0` index was removed, `del item['val'][3]` would actually remove 5th element, not 4th, as we want it to.

Comment: @RomanBodnarchuk -- thanks.  Must still be a little asleep.  I didn't like that part anyway.  I've changed it to a list-comprehension.  Of course, I suppose we could use the iterate backward and pop solution that StevenRumvalski used -- OR, I could just sort remove_idx so that it is descending ... but the list-comp is better.

Comment: @mgilson:  I didn't like the pop solution so I changed it.  I also think I made it cleaner by identifying columns to keep rather than columns to remove.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip
from operator import itemgetter

# create an iterator over columns
columns = izip(*(d['val'] for d in dl))

# make function keeps non-empty columns
keepfunc = itemgetter(*(i for i, c in enumerate(columns) if any(c)))

# apply function to each list
for d in dl:
    d['val'] = list(keepfunc(d['val']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another possible solution (not really efficient but well...). `zip()` is really underrated...

```
# extract the values as a list of list
vals = [item["val"] for item in dl]
# transpose lines to columns
cols = map(list, zip(*lines))
# filter out empty columns
cols = [c for c in cols if filter(None, c)]
# retranspose columns to lines
lines = map(list, zip(*cols))
# build the new dict
output = [
    dict(plat=item["plat"], val=line) for item, line in zip(dl, lines)
    ]
```